# Spring data mongoDB partial index with constraint

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I would like to create a very simple annotated java POJO and save it into mongodb. Basically, it is:

```
@Component("vehicle")
@Scope("prototype")
@Document(collection = "vehicle")
@CompoundIndexes({
        @CompoundIndex(name = "plateNumber_idx", def = "{ 'plateNumber' : 1 }", unique = true),
        @CompoundIndex(name = "vin_idx", def = "{ 'vin' : 1 }", unique = true),
        @CompoundIndex(name = "motorNumber_idx", def = "{ 'motorNumber' : 1 }", unique = true)
})
public class Vehicle {

    private String plateNumber;
    private String vin;
    private String motorNumber;

   ... getters, setters, equal, hash etc. ....
}
```

It is working properly, but in my case I need to add a partial index to motorNumber field. The reason is: not necessary fill this field in, therefore this field can be null. But the other hand, not allowed to be two or more similar motorNumber - except, when those are null. I can add partial index(s) to vehicle collection by hand, but it will be more elegant way to do it by annotations. For example, here is my partial index:

```
{"motorNumber" : {"$exists" : true}}
```

My question is: How can I add this option to @CompoundIndex ? Or there are any other options ?

Comment: Are you looking for `@Indexed(unique = true, sparse = true)`?

Comment: As you can see, Im not an expert at mongodb, but I think, you can use sparse=true, just in null case or when the field not exists. Maybe sparse is the best solution for my question - and you are right - but in other cases when you need another condition ( { age: { $gte: 21 } } sparse won't work. ( I think, my partial index example isn't the best )

Comment: In case anybody interested, there is already a feature request in Spring jira: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1321

Answer (score 7):

I found your question while trying to do much the same thing.

As far as I can tell, neither spring-data-mongodb for spring-boot 1.5.x or 2.0.x supports Partial Indexes via the usual annotations.

However, spring-data-mongodb does allow you to create them programatically:

```
Index myIndex = new Index()
    .background()
    .unique()
    .named("my_index_name")
    .on("indexed_field_1", Sort.Direction.ASC)
    .on("indexed_field_2", Sort.Direction.DESC)
    .partial(PartialIndexFilter.of(
        Criteria.where("criteria_field_1")
        .is("BAR")));

DefaultIndexOperations indexOperations = new DefaultIndexOperations(mongoTemplate, "my_collection");

indexOperations.ensureIndex(myIndex);
```

Comment: Yeh, seems someone made a PR to add the annotation, but in the end they opted for the manual way.
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/pull/380